# Bluetooth stays on after switching off

Tags: bluetooth

I am new to Linux distributions and have just installed Elementary Juno 5.0 on Lenovo T420. The bluetooth is working fine except that when I switch it off from the top system tray on the screen, the bluetooth indicator on the laptop deck is still on. The same is not happening for wi-fi (bluetooth and wi-fi are operated from the same modem?). This is not affecting any functionality, but in Windows switching off bluetooth from wireless manager would turn off the indicator too. Is there a solution?

Comment: You can use `rfkill block bluetooth` and `rfkill unblock bluetooth` to turn it off completely from Terminal. The issue is most likely that the Wifi and bluetooth card are the same and the system is unable to turn just one of them off.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But using the command on Terminal also removes the Bluetooth icon from the system tray. I guess that's all that can be done in Elementary.